# 2 chained AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter resulting in 302 Redirection when 2nd filter tries to write to response stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, restful-authentication, spring-filter

I have 2 filters, `Filter1` and `Filter2`, both of which extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. `Filter1` has successfully done it's job and chained the request to `Filter2`. Now, when `Filter2` throws an `AuthenticationException` and it's handled by Filter2's `onAuthenticationFailure` method, response is written to the response stream with HttpStatus 403 and response is hence committed. But the control is chained back to `Filter1` after `doFilter` method is called (in Filter1) and it's redirecting to '/' url which is resulting in 302 redirected status instead on 403 which I'm expecting. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about skipping filterchain during exception to avoid redirection to '/' url?

It's spring-boot application and both filters are configured in ApplicationConfig.java, with separate ErrorHandlers `Errorhandler1` and `Errorhandler2`. 
`FirstFilter` has set authentication status to true and second filter throws an exception. But since `Response` is already committed by `Errorhandler2` ('AuthenticationFailureHandler') of second filter in chain, but still control goes to Filter1 and redirects to '/'.

```
@Component
public class Filter2CustomErrorhandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        CustomError error = new CustomError();
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(403);
        response.getWriter().write(convertObjectToJson(error));
    }

    private String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

}

public class Filter1 extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public Filter1(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = new CustomAuthenticationToken("some-principal-1", "some-credential-1");
        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    }
}   


public class Filter2 extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public Filter2(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = new CustomAuthenticationToken("some-principal-2", "some-credential-2");
        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);

        throw new SecurityAuthenticationException("some-exception-message", new CustomException());

        //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        //return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the HttpStatus 403 in the RestClient.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- So another way to achieve this is to have single
  `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and multiple providers.
- Individual providers can implement overridden supports method for
  specific `Authentication` type (Ex. `ExampleAuthInstance extends
  Authentication`).
- When you invoke providers from filter like 
  `this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate( exampleAuthInstance )`,
  the provider that supports `ExampleAuthInstance`, authenticate method
  of that provider will be invoked.
- `AuthenticationException` has to be thrown from filter itself and not from providers. Providers rather can throw `CustomSecurityException` with required `HttpStatus` which can then be wrapped in `AuthenticationException` and thrown at filter level. Which will then be delegated to appropriate preconfigured `Failure handler` which might want  to response stream.